# MySQL/php Charset madness: which one is correct?

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

I imported a list of name in mysql, directly from txt file to phpmyadmin, european names.

My html header is set to utf8, mysql is set to utf8.

now the names with accent like **Contè**, display a `<?>` instead of accents.

If i remove the meta ut8, I can see the accents correctly, but everything else breaks, for instance when i upload a file like **Aleš.jpg** the html spit out a unreadable filename..

i'm lost..

Answer (score 0):

It smells like the text file was encoded in latin1 some other encoding.

Can you provide a hex dump of "Contè" as found in the file?  We can help you recognize whether it is utf8 or not.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings shows that è is hex `E8` in latin1 or `C3A8` in utf8.

Once the encoding is determined, the  tag on the html page can be fixed to agree with it.